# How to generate python random numbers on gpu?

Tags: python, gpgpu, numba

I'm new to python programming on gpu. I'm currently trying to generate an array of random numbers on gpu using `numbapro.numpy_support.numpy`. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import numbapro as nbp
from numba.numpy_support import numpy as nbnp

@nbp.vectorize(['float32(int32, int32, float32)'], target='gpu')
def random_syn_weight_mat(n1, n2, prob) :
    A = nbnp.random.random((n1, n2))
    A[nbnp.where(A > prob)] = 0
    return A

W = random_syn_weight_mat(1000, 1000, 0.1)
```

Running this spits out an error that says `nbnp.random.random` is not defined. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should be able to use `A[A>prob]=0` (and skip the `numpy.where`). I have no way of testing if that works on a gpu though.